# iOS Facebook switches back to app between login & permissions

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, permissions

I'm trying to setup my app to publish a simple post to a user's Facebook feed (image url, link, description).  They don't need to use Facebook for anything else so the first time they click "Share" it needs to authorize the app, and the publish permissions.

If they have their credentials stored in the device as of iOS 6 they simply get two alert boxes and it's done with.  But if they don't, or have an older version, it switches out to Safari for login.  My problem is that it is then switching the user back to my app, then immediately back again to Safari to accept the publish permission.  It's very jarring and unprofessional.

What I would like is for the page in Safari to change after the login to the permissions page so they can accept it, and THEN switch back to my app.  I know this can be done because the popular Mixology app does exactly this behavior.  Unfortunately Facebook keeps changing their SDK and all the information I find online is outdated.

Comment: I have a doubt about your plist file.
Your info.plist seems to be formatted incorrectly
Ensure that the url scheme is nested under an item (an array to be exact) called "URL Schemes"

Comment: I'm using the URL Types section that XCode has now, and my FB appID is in the URL Schemes box.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up a solution here: [FacebookSDK presents login UI twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727796/facebooksdk-presents-login-ui-twice/16073570#16073570) to avoid the double switch.

Basically, you can use `openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:` to do what you want. However, you have to handle the special case where the user has signed in to Facebook from the device settings, which requires requests for read and publish permissions into two separate calls.